# Performance inconsistency: What's going on here?

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics

Consider:

```
(*
{numsamps,maxdist,sumnum}={100,1,30}

r=Mean[TransformedDistribution[Tr[Array[x,sumnum]],Array[x,sumnum]\
\[Distributed]OrderDistribution[{DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1,\
maxdist}],numsamps},Range[numsamps-sumnum+1,numsamps]]]];//\
AbsoluteTiming
*)

{numsamps, maxdist, sumnum} = {100, 40, 30}

r = Mean[TransformedDistribution[Tr[Array[x, sumnum]], 
     Array[x, sumnum] \[Distributed] 
      OrderDistribution[{DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, maxdist}], 
        numsamps}, 
       Range[numsamps - sumnum + 1, numsamps]]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

This seems to never finish (I aborted it after minutes).

Now, uncomment the prior code, kill the kernel(s), and run. It completes quickly.

Sometimes when just running the latter section for a small amount of time, aborting execution, then re-running the same, it finishes equally quickly.

I'm quite puzzled by this. Might others confirm this behavior?

Win 10, Mathematica 12.1.1.0

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result.  Running your code with Win 10, Mathematica 12.1.1.0 executes in about 0.18 seconds.

Comment: With v12.1.1 on my Mac the timings are `{0.079603, 0.130357}`